# Gunicorn+eventlet timeout

Tags: django, gevent, gunicorn, eventlet

I try to run gunicorn with eventlet worker (django app):

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -k eventlet -t 5
```

if i have two bad views:

```
def view1(request):
    while 1:
        time.sleep(0.001) #same as eventlet.sleep
    return HttpResponse('ok')

def view2(request):
    while 1:
        pass
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

option -t (--timeout) make sense only for view2 (because worker hangs and gunicorn can understand it). But gunicorn doesn't handle bad view2.

In real case seems we have some infinity loops with time.sleep() or other monkey patched method inside and after some time our application doesn't hangs but will have many infinity green threads and start work slowly.

My question is how i can setup gunicorn to it can understand what something wrong with view1 and restart worker.

Comment: It probably needs a few clarifications. 'make sense only for view2 ... but gunicorn doesn't handle vad view2' - are numbers correct?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to limit maximum time for executing any request? That's a great idea. As of 2013-02, Gunicorn does not support this out of the box.

You can use [eventlet.Timeout](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html) to implement it. Depending on whether you want it quick or to share you could add timeout only into your application or as a feature to Gunicorn. Their [code](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn) is easy to follow.

Comment: yes. My goal is add timeout for each request. We use heroku and their load balancer has 30 sec proxy timeout. So any requests longer than 30 sec doesn't make sense. Thank you. But i really don't want fork gunicorn i hope that there is any standard method. So i like idea to add eventlet.TImeout(30) for each request.